# Password complexity of Firebase Authentication Reset Password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using firebase auth, and create user by email and password, in frontend I control password complexity by using regular expression like `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{6,}`, 
should be at least 6 chars, 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 number, 1 symbol

So far so good.

When user forget his/her password, I call `sendPasswordResetEmail` on firebese auth, and it will send password reset link to user, but when user clicks on the link it has only default rule of min 6 chars, combination of letter and number

I already searched SO, all of the solutions are about `signup`, not `forget password`

Is there any way to control that?

[image]

Comment: There is no way for you to control the password complexity requirements of Firebase Authentication's built-in email+password provider. Even if you control it partially in your UI, users can still call the API. The only way to fully control the password complexity is by creating your own provider. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082508, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60013966, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352865, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49184693

Comment: You could also implement your own email action handler: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler. But as with your current implementation, that'd be a pure client-side implementation too, and users could call the API themselves to bypass your UI.